# itext XFA: InvalidCastException

Tags: linq, itext, itext7

Using itext7 and when trying to load XFA form I'm getting:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Xml.Linq.XText' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.'

Source code:

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(package.PdfTemplate);
pdfReader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
using (var document = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, new PdfWriter(writeMS)))
{
    var acroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, true);
    var xfa = acroForm.GetXfaForm();
    var dataXml = _dataGenerator.GenerateXfaFormData(package);
    xfa.FillXfaForm(dataXml);
    xfa.Write(document);
}
```

The exception is thrown on line

> var acroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, true);

Sample PDF can be seen here: https://programmcze-my.sharepoint.com/personal/nechanicky_programmcze_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=0c18710068a124a58a32e77ad53c4cbb9&authkey=AQvVBZLXNirrISLjvT083XY

Comment: Could you share the entire stack trace?

Comment: Entire stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/uHY4biYn

Answer (score 0):

There indeed was a problem with constructing `XfaForm` which does not contain `<xfa:datasets>` entry.

The problem is fixed in `iText 7.0.5-SNAPSHOT` version. The repository with the sources and the fix can be found [here](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet).